MongoDB seems to use different index than it chooses when using explain
I have a query indexes like below in a fairly large collection:
field1_1: {field1: 1}
field2_1: {field2: 1}
field3_1: {field3: 1}

When I tried to run:
db.getCollection('someCollection').find({
    "field1" : "some value",
    "field2" : 1,
    "field3" : "some ID"
});

The query took more than 1 second. So I tried to run explain(), according to the result, the winner plan should use field3_1 index (see result below).
But if I force index field3_1 hint the query executes less than a second.
And if I force index field1_1 hint the query executes more than a second.
This gives me the impression the index Mongo showed in the explain result (field3_1) is not the same with the index it use on actual run (probably field1_1).
The explain result (I omitted some part due to max size permitted by SO):
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1.0,
        "namespace" : "somedb.someCollection",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [
                {
                    "field3" : {
                        "$eq" : "some-random-id"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "field2" : {
                        "$eq" : 1.0
                    }
                },
                {
                    "field1" : {
                        "$eq" : "some-value"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "$and" : [
                    {
                        "field2" : {
                            "$eq" : 1.0
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "field1" : {
                            "$eq" : "some-value"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "field3" : 1.0
                },
                "indexName" : "field3_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "field3" : [

                    ]
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2.0,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "field3" : [
                        "[\"some-random-id\", \"some-random-id\"]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [/* OMITTED */]
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 1.0,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 0.0,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 3.0,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 3.0,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "$and" : [
                    {
                        "field2" : {
                            "$eq" : 1.0
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "field1" : {
                            "$eq" : "some-value"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "nReturned" : 1.0,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0.0,
            "works" : 5.0,
            "advanced" : 1.0,
            "needTime" : 2.0,
            "needYield" : 0.0,
            "saveState" : 0.0,
            "restoreState" : 0.0,
            "isEOF" : 1.0,
            "invalidates" : 0.0,
            "docsExamined" : 3.0,
            "alreadyHasObj" : 0.0,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "nReturned" : 3.0,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0.0,
                "works" : 4.0,
                "advanced" : 3.0,
                "needTime" : 0.0,
                "needYield" : 0.0,
                "saveState" : 0.0,
                "restoreState" : 0.0,
                "isEOF" : 1.0,
                "invalidates" : 0.0,
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "field3" : 1.0
                },
                "indexName" : "field3_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "field3" : [

                    ]
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2.0,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "field3" : [
                        "[\"some-random-id\", \"some-random-id\"]"
                    ]
                },
                "keysExamined" : 3.0,
                "seeks" : 1.0,
                "dupsTested" : 0.0,
                "dupsDropped" : 0.0,
                "seenInvalidated" : 0.0
            }
        },
        "allPlansExecution" : [
            {
                "nReturned" : 0.0,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0.0,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 4.0,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 4.0,
                "executionStages" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "filter" : {
                        "$and" : [
                            {
                                "field3" : {
                                    "$eq" : "some-random-id"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "field2" : {
                                    "$eq" : 1.0
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "nReturned" : 0.0,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0.0,
                    "works" : 4.0,
                    "advanced" : 0.0,
                    "needTime" : 4.0,
                    "needYield" : 0.0,
                    "saveState" : 0.0,
                    "restoreState" : 0.0,
                    "isEOF" : 0.0,
                    "invalidates" : 0.0,
                    "docsExamined" : 4.0,
                    "alreadyHasObj" : 0.0,
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "nReturned" : 4.0,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0.0,
                        "works" : 4.0,
                        "advanced" : 4.0,
                        "needTime" : 0.0,
                        "needYield" : 0.0,
                        "saveState" : 0.0,
                        "restoreState" : 0.0,
                        "isEOF" : 0.0,
                        "invalidates" : 0.0,
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "field1" : 1.0
                        },
                        "indexName" : "field1_1",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                            "field1" : [

                            ]
                        },
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 2.0,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "field1" : [
                                "[\"some-value\", \"some-value\"]"
                            ]
                        },
                        "keysExamined" : 4.0,
                        "seeks" : 1.0,
                        "dupsTested" : 0.0,
                        "dupsDropped" : 0.0,
                        "seenInvalidated" : 0.0
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "nReturned" : 0.0,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0.0,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 4.0,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 4.0,
                "executionStages" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "filter" : {
                        "$and" : [
                            {
                                "field3" : {
                                    "$eq" : "some-random-id"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "field1" : {
                                    "$eq" : "some-value"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "nReturned" : 0.0,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0.0,
                    "works" : 4.0,
                    "advanced" : 0.0,
                    "needTime" : 4.0,
                    "needYield" : 0.0,
                    "saveState" : 0.0,
                    "restoreState" : 0.0,
                    "isEOF" : 0.0,
                    "invalidates" : 0.0,
                    "docsExamined" : 4.0,
                    "alreadyHasObj" : 0.0,
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "nReturned" : 4.0,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0.0,
                        "works" : 4.0,
                        "advanced" : 4.0,
                        "needTime" : 0.0,
                        "needYield" : 0.0,
                        "saveState" : 0.0,
                        "restoreState" : 0.0,
                        "isEOF" : 0.0,
                        "invalidates" : 0.0,
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "field2" : 1.0
                        },
                        "indexName" : "field2_1",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                            "field2" : [

                            ]
                        },
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 2.0,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "field2" : [
                                "[1.0, 1.0]"
                            ]
                        },
                        "keysExamined" : 4.0,
                        "seeks" : 1.0,
                        "dupsTested" : 0.0,
                        "dupsDropped" : 0.0,
                        "seenInvalidated" : 0.0
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "nReturned" : 0.0,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0.0,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 4.0,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 1.0,
                "executionStages" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "filter" : {
                        "$and" : [
                            {
                                "field3" : {
                                    "$eq" : "some-random-id"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "field1" : {
                                    "$eq" : "some-value"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "field2" : {
                                    "$eq" : 1.0
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "nReturned" : 0.0,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0.0,
                    "works" : 4.0,
                    "advanced" : 0.0,
                    "needTime" : 4.0,
                    "needYield" : 0.0,
                    "saveState" : 0.0,
                    "restoreState" : 0.0,
                    "isEOF" : 0.0,
                    "invalidates" : 0.0,
                    "docsExamined" : 1.0,
                    "alreadyHasObj" : 0.0,
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "AND_SORTED",
                        "nReturned" : 1.0,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0.0,
                        "works" : 4.0,
                        "advanced" : 1.0,
                        "needTime" : 3.0,
                        "needYield" : 0.0,
                        "saveState" : 0.0,
                        "restoreState" : 0.0,
                        "isEOF" : 0.0,
                        "invalidates" : 0.0,
                        "flagged" : 0.0,
                        "failedAnd_0" : 1.0,
                        "failedAnd_1" : 0.0,
                        "inputStages" : [
                            {
                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                "nReturned" : 3.0,
                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0.0,
                                "works" : 3.0,
                                "advanced" : 3.0,
                                "needTime" : 0.0,
                                "needYield" : 0.0,
                                "saveState" : 0.0,
                                "restoreState" : 0.0,
                                "isEOF" : 0.0,
                                "invalidates" : 0.0,
                                "keyPattern" : {
                                    "field3" : 1.0
                                },
                                "indexName" : "field3_1",
                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                    "field3" : [

                                    ]
                                },
                                "isUnique" : false,
                                "isSparse" : false,
                                "isPartial" : false,
                                "indexVersion" : 2.0,
                                "direction" : "forward",
                                "indexBounds" : {
                                    "field3" : [
                                        "[\"some-random-id\", \"some-random-id\"]"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "keysExamined" : 3.0,
                                "seeks" : 1.0,
                                "dupsTested" : 0.0,
                                "dupsDropped" : 0.0,
                                "seenInvalidated" : 0.0
                            },
                            {
                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                "nReturned" : 1.0,
                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0.0,
                                "works" : 1.0,
                                "advanced" : 1.0,
                                "needTime" : 0.0,
                                "needYield" : 0.0,
                                "saveState" : 0.0,
                                "restoreState" : 0.0,
                                "isEOF" : 0.0,
                                "invalidates" : 0.0,
                                "keyPattern" : {
                                    "field1" : 1.0
                                },
                                "indexName" : "field1_1",
                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                    "field1" : [

                                    ]
                                },
                                "isUnique" : false,
                                "isSparse" : false,
                                "isPartial" : false,
                                "indexVersion" : 2.0,
                                "direction" : "forward",
                                "indexBounds" : {
                                    "field1" : [
                                        "[\"some-value\", \"some-value\"]"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "keysExamined" : 1.0,
                                "seeks" : 1.0,
                                "dupsTested" : 0.0,
                                "dupsDropped" : 0.0,
                                "seenInvalidated" : 0.0
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            /** SOME PLANS OMITTED **/
        ]
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "someHost",
        "port" : 27017.0,
        "version" : "3.4.24-3.0",
        "gitVersion" : "f86383fc4327d70eb4abaea689e609333e924db6"
    },
    "ok" : 1.0
}


Anyone ever experience this? What makes this behaviour to happen? Any way to know actual index mongo use when executing query?

less or more than a second is not reliable/visible time difference. It's very short interval. I see no real evidence yet that winning plan is not used.

If this "find by all three fields" query is frequent, rather than just field2 or just field3, then you should create a compound/multi-key index for those three fields: field1_1_field2_1_field3_1: {field1: 1, field2: 1, field3: 1}.

"The query took more than 1 second." and "... But if I force index field3_1 hint the query executes less than a second." How did you measure this time? Note the "winningPlan" shows the index used with the query.

To begin with some practical advice, I very much agree with the comment from @aneroid. A compound index is going to be more efficient for this query than any of the three single field indexes individually. We don't have enough details to say how much more efficient it might be, but it's possible that it could be quite a bit depending mostly on the selectivity of the query predicates.
Now onto the topic you're asking about, namely the apparent discrepancy with the explain() output.


This gives me the impression the index Mongo showed in the explain result (field3_1) is not the same with the index it use on actual run (probably field1_1).
Anyone ever experience this? What makes this behaviour to happen?

Yes, this can absolutely happen. In short, this is related to the caching of query plans. You can read more on the topic here in the documentation.
Rather than going through all of the work to pick a plan with which a query can be executed every time a request is sent to the database, it instead attempts to remember its decision and reuse it later. In general this is very useful for reducing the amount of work that the database needs to do and ultimately results in faster responses to queries. There's a flow chart in the link above which shows how the system will look for an existing plan in the cache to use. In the steady state for most systems, using cached plans is probably the most common path that a query takes.
When you request an explain plan from the system what you are asking it to do is to describe what execution plan it would choose and why it would choose it if the query were planned by scratch. This is different and basically unrelated to checking to see what (if any) plan is currently cached for the query.


Any way to know actual index mongo use when executing query?

There are a few potential avenues here, but the two most worth mentioning are:

The slow query log
Inspecting the plan cache

For the first, the mongod process automatically captures operations that exceed a specific duration in its log file. The default value is 100 milliseconds, so your queries that execute in ~1 second may be getting captured already. If so, you could check the log file already and the associated log lines would include a planSummary telling you which index was used. The threshold and process for doing this if using Atlas or some other managed service may vary.
For the second part, you may wish to use the $planCacheStats aggregation stage to look at the cached plan directly. Although it's been removed from the explain output in this question, there should be a queryHash field included in it. You can add that value to a subsequent $match stage in the pipeline to limit the output to be specific to the query of interest. There's an example here in the documentation of this which looks as follows:
db.orders.aggregate( [
   { $planCacheStats: { } },
   { $match: { planCacheKey: "B1435201"} }
] )

Notice the isActive field in that output corresponds with the Active and Inactive states from the flow diagram mentioned earlier.
The output here should include the actual values from the query when the cached entry was made active. The actual values are important for the query plan selection process.

One other thing comes to mind, somewhat related to the last point above. The explain output you've shared is clearly not representative of the actual values that are being used to run the query when it is taking ~1 second to complete. Specifically when we look at the metrics we see:
        "nReturned" : 1.0,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 0.0,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 3.0,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 3.0,

The execution time reported here is inclusive of actually planning the query (which is not really part of the runtime when using cached entries). The extremely low number of items being processed basically means that we can't draw any meaningful conclusions from the plan that was selected anyway. It would be (much) more informative if the explain was generated using the actual values from the problematic executions. This would at least give more relevant information about the runtime metrics for the various plans available to it and perhaps help answer the question about why the other plan was selected in the first place.
